# Why is my boot time slower after upgrade?

Tags: 11.10, boot, performance

My Ubuntu 11.10 boots very slowly after I do a clean install into my desktop HP Pavilion with the following specs:

1. Intel Core i5-750
2. 4GB of RAM
3. NVIDIA Geforce GF315.

How can I fix this? I compared its speed to Ubuntu 11.04, which I used before. 11.04 boots faster when starting up and shutting down.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know WHY booting takes longer with 11.10 than with 11.04, but it's very well known that it does.  It is not you or your computer; it's the way it is for everyone.  I hope that with future fixes - and the next release - they can make it faster again, but for the time being I think you'll just have to live with it.  (Unless it's taking several minutes or more; in that case, you do have a problem.)

Answer (score 1):

Like Kelley stated, Ubuntu 11.10 is slower in boot times for everyone, not just you. ;)

Proved by various Phoronix tests: http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ubuntu_oneiric_oktoberfest&num=2

I am hoping that Ubuntu's boot speed will become faster in the 12.04 LTS release as bugs are squashed and performance tweaked.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem while using 12.04. I dont why but I installed `kubuntu-desktop` and boot time started to be a little bit faster than with Unity. You can try it:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop
```